# Как переопределить view только одной модели в админке Laravel voyager?

Tags: laravel

Вот так:
https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/customization/overriding-files

Я переопределил view для одной модели - заменил контент для batches - а оно заменило и все остальные (захожу в категории, там тот же view что для batches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
нужно добавить в переопределяемый файл
@if(url()->current() === url('batches'))
    переопределяемый
@else
   копируем с основного шапку и контент
@endif
```